# How to continue looping while the condition is false

Tags: java, loops

I want my program to do the certain code only if the actors variable is <=5 && >0
else I want to go back and ask different question again:

```
System.out.println("\nEnter actors number(max.5): ");

        int actorsNumber = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine();

        if (actorsNumber <= 5 && actorsnumber>0) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= actorsNumber; i++) {
                System.out.println("\nEnter name and surname of the " + i + " actor: ");
                String[] parts2 = scanner.nextLine().split("\\s+");
                String actName = parts2[0];
                String actSurname = parts2[1];
                actorName.add(actName);
                actorSurname.add(actSurname);
            }

        }
```

So when the condition is false for example actors number = 7 then I want to tell the user: "Enter the valid actors number(1-5)" and do the for loop again if the actorsnumber is 1-5 instead ask again "Enter the valid actors number(1-5)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ask user to enter number in a loop. The condition of the loop will be the condition of your if. Then after exiting the loop (which means user enter a correct number), enter your for loop.

This will look like that :

```
int actorsNumber = -1; //force a wrong value at the beginning
while(actorsNumber < 1 || actorsNumber > 5) {
    //Ask user to enter a number between 1 and 5
    //store this number in actorsNumber
}
//As we exited the while-loop, actorsNumber is between 1 and 5
//Put your for-loop here
```

Comment: it works, but I wanted to firstly ask "Add actors number" and then if the user type wrong (for example 7) - ask different question like "You entered wrong number - it must be in range 0-5" and keep looping that question if the answer is wrong. But thanks for the sollution.

Comment: To do so, just ask one time before the loop. If the user input is correct it wont enter the loop. If it's false it will loop, so you can print another message

Answer (score 0):

```
    while(!scanner.nextLine().equals("quit")) {
        if (actorsNumber <= 5 && actorsnumber>0) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= actorsNumber; i++) {
                System.out.println("\nEnter name and surname of the " + i + "    actor: ");
                String[] parts2 = scanner.nextLine().split("\\s+");
                String actName = parts2[0];
                String actSurname = parts2[1];
                actorName.add(actName);
                actorSurname.add(actSurname);
            }

         }
     }
```

Or something like that, point is, use a while loop on the scanner.

Answer (score 0):

As @apexlol stated, your code should be in a loop. However, `do-while` loop is more convenient than `while` loop since that way, the loop executes at least once no matter what.